# How can I do Google chart animation?

Tags: jquery, html, google-visualization

I need help to do google chart animation, I want that the donut is fenced refilling during 5 seconds. I dont know do it. Thx for help.
My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">        

      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});    

      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data.addRows([
          ['Mujeres', 9],
          ['Onions', 1],
          ['Olives', 1],
          ['Zucchini', 1],
          ['Pepperoni', 2]
        ]);

        var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300,
                        'is3D': true,
                       'animation': { duration: 1000, easing: 'out' }
                   };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('estusuario'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
        setTimeout(function (){
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }, 1000);    
      }          

    </script>
```

Comment: Use setInterval instead of setTimeout

Comment: what does `refilling` mean? new data? Please give full details of expectations

Comment: The animation provided by the API does not support PieCharts [Read: Supported Modifications](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/animation)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in the comments, the animation provided by the API does not support PieCharts

Read the [Supported Modifications](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/animation) topic

You can change it using `setValue` and redrawing the chart...
if you want to animate it, I sugest you use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame)

[Playground](http://jsbin.com/riqaru/4/edit?html,js,output)

```js
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});    
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
var options = {
  'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
  'width':400,
  'height':300,
  'is3D': true
}; 
var chart, data, array = [
  ['Mujeres', 9],
  ['Onions', 1],
  ['Olives', 1],
  ['Zucchini', 1],
  ['Pepperoni', 2]
];
var estusuario = document.getElementById('estusuario');
var button = document.getElementById('add');
function drawChart () { 
  data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
  data.addRows(array);
  chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(estusuario);
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
function changeChart () {
  var x = data.getValue(1, 1);
  data.setValue(1, 1, x + 1);
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
button.addEventListener('click', changeChart);
```

```html
<button id="add">Add</button>
<div id="estusuario"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
</body>
```